# Slick.js showing scrollbar on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Slick.js slider is showing a scrollbar on mobile, allowing the page to be scrolled down. Everything is working 100% on desktop, even when the browser window is condensed to under 800px, activating the mobile layout. I have tried changing `position` and `display` settings but to no avail. I have a feeling this could be something to do specifically with Safari on iOS? See GIF below for visual explanation.

**GIF Visual**

[image: Slick.js Scrollbar on Mobile]

**HTML**

```
<body>
                
<div id="mob-menu" class="mobile-nav">
    <div id="hn-but"><a href="index.html"><p>Hannah Neville</p></a></div>
    <div id="men-but"><a href="#" id="menu-open" class="showhide"><span>Menu</span></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" id="info-mob"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></a></div>
    <div id="title-but"><a href="#"><p>Herbal Essences</p></a></div>            
    <div><a href="#" id="dark-btn" onclick="darkmode()"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></div>
</div>    

<div class="image-slider">
    <div class="image-div"><img class="image" src="assets/herbal-essences/Herbal-Essences1.png"></div>
    <div class="image-div"><img class="image" src="assets/herbal-essences/Herbal-Essences2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image-div"><video id="he-vid" class="video" autoplay muted loop><source src="assets/herbal-essences/Herbal-Essences3.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></div>
</div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-slider {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

img,
video {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.image,
.video {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 15rem);
    max-width: calc(100vw - 2.5rem);
    margin: 0 auto; /* it centers any block level element */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
/* Slick Image Slider */    
    
$('.image-slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    arrows: false,
    swipe: true,
});
    
$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('.image-slider').slick('slickPrev');
  });
    
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('.image-slider').slick('slickNext');
  });
```

Comment: your question is quite unclear to me. please elaborate.

do you want to hide scrollbar?

Comment: Yes, so I don't want this page to scroll up/down at all on mobile. The slider should be fixed in the centre, and only allow the user to swipe left/right through the images. Currently if the user tries to scroll up/down the page and the slider move down a small amount. Hopefully that's clear! Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `image-slider` in a div and applying your position, overflow, and flex classes to that? Then your `justify-content: center` will apply to the slideshow to center it vertically.

Comment: @EdLucas Thank you! This has done the job :) I had tried wrapping it in another div earlier today, but for whatever reason it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow: hidden;` on the body tag like this:

1. for right and bottom scroll use:

   ```
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
   ```
2. for right side scroll only use:

   ```
    body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
   ```
3. for bottom scroll only use:

   ```
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
   ```

In your case apply 2nd option in global or header section.

hope this work for you.

Comment: This does work BUT it then of course disables any scrolling elements which I have on the rest of the site. I have tried applying `overflow-y: hidden` just to the `.image-slider` `div` but it didn't work

Comment: .mobile-nav { overflow: hidden !important; }  try this for mobile

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.slick-slide
{
    height: inherit !important;
}
```